# Is there any way to write getValue(t) function which work for the both the row value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, arrays

I want to write getValue(t) function in a way which can able to change the row based on array value, but I'm stuck while implementing this function. For separate function is working fine but not able to do in just one function.

```js
var rowCount = $('#versionMainTable tr').length - 1;
console.log(rowCount);

// This mapping is mandatory
  const arrTd = {
  '0.1.22': [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  '0.1.23': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  '0.1.29': [1,'',3,'',5,'',7,'',9,'']
};

const arrTd1 = {
  '0.1.30': [1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  '0.1.31': [2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  '0.1.32': [3,3,3,'',5,'',7,'',9,'']
};


// Generic way to work this function  (Need help to write Generic function which work for all the above data).  ???

function getValue(t){
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr#itemsmodel1 td');

}


function getValue(t) {
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr#itemsmodel1 td');
  arrTd[t.value].forEach((value, idx) => cells[idx + 3].innerText = value);
}

function getValue1(t) {
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr#itemsmodel2 td');
  arrTd1[t.value].forEach((value, idx) => cells[idx + 3].innerText = value);
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id="versionMainTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <th>#</th><th>Service Name</th><th>Chart Number</th><th>intgus1</th><th>qaus1</th><th>loadus1</th><th>appstaging</th><th>produs1</th><th>prodeu1</th><th>prodeu2</th><th>prodca1</th><th>prodanz1</th><th>prodsg1</th>
    </thead>

    <tr id = "itemsmodel1">
        <td>1</td><td>activity-registry</td>
        <td>
            <select id="select1" onchange="getValue(this)"><option disabled>Chart Version</option><option value="0.1.22" selected>0.1.22</option><option value="0.1.23">0.1.23</option><option value="0.1.29">0.1.29</option></select>
        </td>
            <td>0</td><td></td><td>26</td><td></td><td>26</td><td>31</td><td>31</td><td></td><td>31</td><td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id = "itemsmodel2">
      <td>2</td><td>emm</td><td><select id="select2" onchange="getValue1(this)"><option disabled>Chart Version</option><option value="0.1.30" selected>1.0.30</option><option value="0.1.31">1.0.31</option><option value="0.1.32">1.0.32</option></select></td>
      <td>0</td><td>0</td><td></td><td>1</td><td></td><td>16</td><td>19</td><td></td><td>14</td><td>43</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help is highly appreciated, I'm trying this to do but unable to find any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. You can store the reference to the object-to-be used in a data attribute. `<tr data-useobj="arrTd">`. Also all calls to `getValue(t)` can be the same (no need for `getValue1(t)` etc).

Here is a testable snippet.

```
function getValue(t) {
  const tr = t.closest('tr'); // find the closest parent <tr>
  const cells = tr.querySelectorAll('td'); // get the collection of cells for that tr
  let useobj = this[tr.dataset.useobj] // the object we'll use is the one referenced in the data attribute
  useobj[t.value].forEach((value, idx) => cells[idx + 3].innerText = value);
}
```

```js
// Return no. of row in table
var rowCount = $('#versionMainTable tr').length - 1;
console.log(rowCount);

// This mapping is mandatory
var arrTd = {
  '0.1.22': [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  '0.1.23': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  '0.1.29': [1, '', 3, '', 5, '', 7, '', 9, '']
};

var arrTd1 = {
  '0.1.30': [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  '0.1.31': [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  '0.1.32': [3, 3, 3, '', 5, '', 7, '', 9, '']
};


function getValue(t) {
  const tr = t.closest('tr');
  const cells = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
  let useobj = this[tr.dataset.useobj]
  useobj[t.value].forEach((value, idx) => cells[idx + 3].innerText = value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"> -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script> -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Test Row</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="versionMainTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Service Name</th>
      <th>Chart Number</th>
      <th>intgus1</th>
      <th>qaus1</th>
      <th>loadus1</th>
      <th>appstaging</th>
      <th>produs1</th>
      <th>prodeu1</th>
      <th>prodeu2</th>
      <th>prodca1</th>
      <th>prodanz1</th>
      <th>prodsg1</th>
    </thead>

    <tr id="itemsmodel1" data-useobj='arrTd'>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>activity-registry</td>
      <td>
        <select id="select1" onchange="getValue(this)">
          <option disabled>Chart Version</option>
          <option value="0.1.22" selected>0.1.22</option>
          <option value="0.1.23">0.1.23</option>
          <option value="0.1.29">0.1.29</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="itemsmodel2" data-useobj='arrTd1'>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>emm</td>
      <td>
        <select id="select2" onchange="getValue(this)">
          <option disabled>Chart Version</option>
          <option value="0.1.30" selected>1.0.30</option>
          <option value="0.1.31">1.0.31</option>
          <option value="0.1.32">1.0.32</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>43</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```